# Docker networking, backend connection problem

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I have three containers
Nginx container to forward requests to app container.

App container for React client

Proxy-server container serves as proxy server between react client and apis

I trying to hide backend from outer world with docker networking

I have the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  backend:
  frontend:

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: services/nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - frontend
  app:
    env_file: '.env'
    build:
      context: services/app/client
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - '~/.bash_history:/.bash_history'
    depends_on:
      - proxy-server
  proxy-server:
    env_file: '.env'
    build:
      context: services/app/server
    networks:
      - backend
```

Dockerfile of proxy-server

```
# build environment
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN yarn
COPY . /app

CMD ["node", "./bin/www"]
```

Dokerfile of app

```
# build environment
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN yarn
COPY . /app
RUN yarn build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I try to access the proxy server from app with
http://proxy-server:4000
but Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: the docker networks are not shared outside. You don't need this separation. Anyway if you enter the `app` while it's running and try to execute `ping proxy-server` would it find it?

Comment: There is no need to  create 2 network since you don't expose your port